# applicationDidFinishLaunching variable scope issue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsarray

Just a quick question. I have an NSArray that is generated in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method, but for some reason the array isn't being used by other methods and it is saying that it is being unused.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching... {
    NSArray* songsArray = [root nodesForXPath:@".//dict/dict/dict" error:nil];

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn... {
    for(NSXMLElement* song in songsArray) {
```

I have declared the variable in the header file also.

Cheers,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `songsArray` as a *local* variable, it's not visible outside `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

If you have already declared your variable in header, you need to just assign it:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching... {
    songsArray = [root nodesForXPath:@".//dict/dict/dict" error:nil];
```

**Note on memory management:**
If you are not using ARC, you also need to `retain` your array, otherwise it will be autoreleased at the end of `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, and your variable will be pointing to a deallocated memory, and your app will crash.

And don't forget to `release` it in `dealloc` (again, if you are not in ARC land).

Answer (score 2):

You may have declared a `songsArray` in the header, but you're not assigning it in `-application:didFinishLaunching:`. Instead you have created a local variable with the same name that is only going to stay in scope until the end of the method. Assign your ivar like this:

```
songsArray = [root nodesForXPath:@".//dict/dict/dict" error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `songsArray` in the scope of the method, you need to add this as a class variable as follows:

**MyApplication.h**

```
@interface MyApplication {
    NSArray *songsArray;
}
```

**MyApplication.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching… {
    songsArray = [[root nodesForXPath:@".//dict/dict/dict" error:nil] retain];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [songsArray release];
    songsArray = nil;
}
```

Note, you will also need to `retain` it so the array is not release automatically when the `NSAutoReleasePool` is drained.